# Remove or Minus the stock in inventory with order

Tags: sql

how can I minus the stock quantity per variety in tblInventory based on the number of orders per quantity and weight in the tblOrders

Order Table

| id | orderid | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | J1 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 10 | 120 |
| 2 | J2 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 5 | 100 |
| 3 | J3 | Duck | 2.0 | 2 | 250 |
| 4 | J4 | Turkey | 4.6 | 4 | 350 |

Inventory Table

| id | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 20 | 120 |
| 2 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 15 | 100 |
| 3 | Duck | 1.6 | 5 | 250 |
| 4 | Turkey | 1.6 | 9 | 350 |
| 5 | Native Chicken | 1.9 | 20 | 120 |
| 6 | Chicken Broiler | 2.5 | 15 | 100 |
| 7 | Duck | 1.7 | 5 | 250 |
| 8 | Turkey | 4.7 | 9 | 350 |

expected Result in Inventory Table after adding orders. The quantity in the specific weight and variety should be reduced.

| id | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 10 | 120 |
| 2 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 10 | 100 |
| 3 | Duck | 1.6 | 3 | 250 |
| 4 | Turkey | 1.6 | 5 | 350 |
| 5 | Native Chicken | 1.9 | 20 | 120 |
| 6 | Chicken Broiler | 2.5 | 15 | 100 |
| 7 | Duck | 1.7 | 5 | 250 |
| 8 | Turkey | 4.7 | 9 | 350 |

Comment: Please tag the DMBS you are using.

Comment: Quantity for id 3 in inventory table reduced by 2 but there is not entry on order table for 1.6 kg of duck

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE inv
SET inv.quantity = inv.quantity - ord.quantity
FROM tblInventory inv
INNER JOIN tblOrders ord
ON inv.id = ord.id AND inv.weight = ord.weight
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple SQL statement to achieve that :

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    i.variety,
    i.weight,
    i.quantity - COALESCE(o.quantity, 0) AS quantity,
    i.price
FROM
    inventory_table i
LEFT JOIN
    order_table o
    ON i.variety = o.variety
        AND i.weight = o.weight
```

Answer (score 0):

To update inventory table from order table:

Schema:

```
 create table orders(id int,orderid varchar(10),variety varchar(50),weight float,   quantity int, price int);
 insert into orders values(1,   'J1',   'Native Chicken',   1.6,    10, 120);
 insert into orders values(2,   'J2',   'Chicken Broiler',  2.3,    5,  100);
 insert into orders values(3,   'J3',   'Duck'  ,               2.0,    2,  250);
 insert into orders values(4,   'J4',   'Turkey'    ,       4.6,    4,  350);
 
 create table Inventory (id int, variety varchar(50),weight float,quantity int, price int);
 insert into Inventory values(1,    'Native Chicken',   1.6,    20, 120);
 insert into Inventory values(2,    'Chicken Broiler',  2.3,    15, 100);
 insert into Inventory values(3,    'Duck'  ,               1.6,    5,  250);
 insert into Inventory values(4,    'Turkey'    ,       1.6,    9,  350);
 insert into Inventory values(5,    'Native Chicken',   1.9,    20, 120);
 insert into Inventory values(6,    'Chicken Broiler',  2.5,    15, 100);
 insert into Inventory values(7,    'Duck'  ,               1.7,    5,  250);
 insert into Inventory values(8,    'Turkey',           4.7,    9,  350);
```

Update Query:

```
 update inventory i
   set quantity= i.quantity - COALESCE(o.quantity, 0) 
 from orders o
 where i.variety = o.variety AND i.weight = o.weight
```

Select query:

```
 select * from inventory order by id
```

Output:

| id | variety | weight | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Native Chicken | 1.6 | 10 | 120 |
| 2 | Chicken Broiler | 2.3 | 10 | 100 |
| 3 | Duck | 1.6 | 5 | 250 |
| 4 | Turkey | 1.6 | 9 | 350 |
| 5 | Native Chicken | 1.9 | 20 | 120 |
| 6 | Chicken Broiler | 2.5 | 15 | 100 |
| 7 | Duck | 1.7 | 5 | 250 |
| 8 | Turkey | 4.7 | 9 | 350 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2be04eb01aa7d25d832d04ba50dae0f)*

Comment: I tried using this but everytime I add a new product the products that has been added first keeps on decreasing

Comment: Please clarify a little more. Isn't it your goal to reduce inventory quantity if there is matching variety and weight in order table/

Comment: Exactly, but whenever I try your code the previous orders were still reducing from the inventory

Comment: Then I would suggest to update inventory table within same transaction of order table insertion. or to use after insert trigger on orders table. which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    tblInventory
SET

Table_A.weight =Table_A.weight-Table_B.weight
Table_A.quantity=Table_A.quantity-Table_B.quantity


FROM
    tblInventory AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN tblOrders AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.weight = Table_B.weight
AND Table_A.quantity = Table_B.quantity
```